# How to tap on a list item component in Blackberry Cascades qml and qt

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml, blackberry-10

I asked this question before in other wording, but maybe the question was poorly worded, and no one seemed to answer.  I have been searching for a working example showing an answer to my question, but I cannot find any.  I really need to know the answer to this.

In Blackberry Cascades, QML, QT & C++, how do I respond to someone tapping on an item in a list?

Is the answer to do with involving TapHandler and ListView?  If so, could someone please show me how to connect the two, because I cannot find any examples of that on the internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to respond to clicking on list items in a list view in qml, C++ qt, in Blackberry 10 Cascades](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647816/how-to-respond-to-clicking-on-list-items-in-a-list-view-in-qml-c-qt-in-black)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a boiler plate example, similar to code I use in my Cascades apps:

```
ListView { 

dataModel: XmlDataModel { 
    source: "data/items.xml"
          function doResponse(){} 
} 

listItemComponents: [ 
    ListItemComponent { 
        type: "item" 
            StandardListItem {
            id: listItem
            title: ListItemData.title 

            onTouch: { 
                if (event.isUp()){               
                    listItem.ListItem.view.dataModel.doResponse();                
                } 
            } 
        } 
    }     
]   
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, but I tried your answer, but I got this error:

main.qml:227: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: doResponse

Any qml or C++ variable or object I try to reference from inside the listItemComponents[] gives that error, but not when I do the same thing outside listItemComponents[].

Comment: @user1296259 Try the new code, getting references right from within a StandardListItem object can be tricky :-)

Comment: Thank you, but I found another solution.  I basically did something like this: I put "onCreationCompleted: {Qt.lblX = lblX}" just after "Page {", and then in the "onTouch: { if (event.isUp()) { }" I put Qt.lblX.setText(index.ListItem.indexPath[1]), then I called my C++ function from lblX using onTextChanged (and I made lblX invisible)

Comment: Yeah, the doResponse() wasn't central to your original question. I was just being helpful.

I answered your original question of "how do I respond to someone tapping on an item in a list" with: onTouch: { if (event.isUp())...} so you should accept my answer.